# Pushed code on local branch lost after rebase

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

I have a `feature-1` branch. Eventually it will be merged into my `develop` branch which is shared among my team. After some change, I make a commit {1} and push it to the origin `feature-1` branch.

When I rebase my `feature-1` into `develop` , there is no conflict and git said : `Your branch and 'origin/feature-1' have diverged, and have 20 and 1 different commits each, respectively.` At this point, people will do a git push --force and that is all. But I notice that all of my change in commit {1} at local after rebase are lost, so I can not do a force push because my commit {1} on origin/feature-1 will be lost.

Is it a normal behaviour of git when it ignore my pushed commit when rebase? and Shouldn't I push commit before rebase?

Comment: `feature-1` has been shared as evidenced by `'origin/feature-1'`.

Comment: So if the branch exist on remote, It count as shared although no one except me working on it?

Comment: We're splitting hairs, but yes once a branch has been pushed you can consider it to be shared.

Comment: @hai_uit, Could you get useful information from Marina's suggestion?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I've not tried it yet because after post the question. My team was given a heavy working schedule included weekend. I will have some day off this weekend, I will try to test it in my local machine and comment to his answer asap.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT see my comment in Marina's answer.

Answer (score 1):

For your situations, it's ok to force push `feature-1` branch to remote.

We can illustrate by graphs as below:

**Before rebasing `feature-1` into `develop` branch**, the commit history should be:

```
...---C-F1                   feature-1, origin/feature-1
       \
        D1---D2---...---D20  develop, origin/develop
```

**After executing `git rebase develop` command on `feature-1` branch**, the commit history will be:

```
...---C-F1    origin/feature-1
       \
        D1---D2---...---D20---F1'  feature-1
                         |
              develop, origin/develop
```

So git will detect `feature-1` branch "`Your branch and 'origin/feature-1' have diverged, and have 20 and 1 different commits each, respectively`".

And if you force push `feature-1` branch, and update `feature-1` branch will on the top on `develop` branch, and you can merge `feature-1` branch into `develop` branch then.

Comment: I currently cannot reproduce my issue in my local machine. When I am on feature-1 and rebase develop, git report conflict (if there are ones) and I can see code of both code of develop and master. After rebase, none of my change on feature-1 lost and I can simple `git push -f` . But sometime, in my machine at my company, my changes in feature-1 lost after rebase, so I can not force push because it will overwrite origin/feature-1.

Comment: @hai_uit for changes on feature-1 lost or not, it depends on how you solve the rebase conflicts. Besides, if you do not want to force push, then you can use merge instead of rebase.